# Failed to import "File name": Invalid post type jetpack-portfolio

Tags: errors, import, plugin-jetpack

I'm importing all my content from wordpress.com to wordpress.org but keep getting the error Failed to import “Post Name”: Invalid post type jetpack-portfolio. I need to transfer all my portfolio and blog posts across but it isn't working. Can any one tell me how to solve this?

Comment: You need to install Jetpack so that the jetpack-portfolio post type is available on your site. For further help you should contact Jetpack support, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: I already have Jetpack installed on the new website... Do you think it could be something else? Or a specific version of Jetpack?

Comment: You’ll need to ask them for support.

Comment: close voting as wordpress.com do not run "vanilla" wordpress and its export is not supported by the canonical import plugins. As said above you will need to consult wordpress.com's support